# JdbcCursorItemReader commit interval

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

According to this [document](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/4.0.x/reference/html/index-single.html#chunkOrientedProcessing) , it states that in a "chunk-oriented" processing the read amount of the reader is the same amount of the "commit-interval". 
I wonder if all out-of-the-box readers follow the same principle.
Let's say for `JdbcCursorItemReader` does this indicate that it selects the "first" hundred only(*commit interval = 100*) based on the SQL statement given, or does it select all the data first and process chunk-by-chunk with the commit interval amount?

Documents that will help clarify are much appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Item readers are not aware of the chunk size. It is the chunk oriented step that controls when to call the item reader to get the next item until a chunk is created or the datasource is exhausted (item reader returns `null`).

> Let's say for JdbcCursorItemReader does this indicate that it selects the "first" hundred only(commit interval = 100) based on the SQL statement given, or does it select all the data first and process chunk-by-chunk with the commit interval amount?

If the commit-interval (or `chunkSize`) is set to 100, the `JdbcCursorItemReader` does not read the first 100 items or select all data, it will actually read [`fetchSize`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/4.1.x/api/org/springframework/batch/item/database/AbstractCursorItemReader.html#setFetchSize-int-) items. With the example of `chunkSize=100`, if the `fetchSize=10`, then the `JdbcCursorItemReader` will perform 10 queries to the database for each chunk.

I hope this clarifies the relation between those parameters.

Comment: Does it mean chunkSize should always be greater then fetchSize? OR we are already having fetchSize what is the use of chunk ?

Comment: No, fetchSize and chunkSize are not related. If chunkSize > fetchSize, the step will need two db calls to create a chunk. Otherwise, there will a single call to fill in a chunk.